# Prove that $A\cap B= \emptyset$ iff $A \cap B' = A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove $A\cap B= \emptyset$ iff $A \cap B' = A$.

I can prove its reverse, I mean $A \cap B' = A$  iff $A \cap B = \emptyset$. I can also understand why this would be true, 
$A \cap B = \emptyset$  iff $A \cap B' = A$.

Comment: Iff is symmetric relation, if you prove one way you prove the other(a iff b is means that a is equivalent to b, so b is equivalent to a hence b iff a). Did you write iff instead of if?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, $A$ must intersect the complement of $B$ somewhere. So....

Comment: For any set $C$, $A\cap C\subset A$

Comment: This would be true if, for example, it said "$A \cap B = \varnothing$ iff $A \subseteq A \cap B'$" or "$A \cap B = \varnothing$ iff $A \cap B' = A$".

Comment: No need! I can now do.

Comment: It's wrong as stated. If $A = B$ then $A \cap B' \subseteq A$ is trivially true, as $\emptyset \subseteq A$ always holds, while the left side is then false unless $A = B = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

$A \cap B' \subseteq A $ always true

$$ p \; \text{and} \; q \implies p $$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

we can easily interpret this in a Venn diagram for understanding

Answer (score 0):

$x∈A∩B$

$⇒x∈A∧x∈B$

$⇒x∈A∩B′∧x∈B[∵A∩B′=A]$

$⇒(x∈A∧x∈B′)∧x∈B$

$⇒(x∈A∧x∉B)∧x∈B$

$⇒x∈A∧(x∉B∧x∈B)$

$⇒x∈A∧x∉∅$

$⇒x∉∅$

$∴A∩B⊆∅$

$As$ $∅$ $is$ $an$ $empty$ $set$ , $∅⊆A∩B$

$∴ A∩B=∅$

$[proved]$